# Insert a row for each foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which its name is 'comment' and it has foreign key for 'customer' table as below:

```
id
customer_id(FK)
content
...
```

I have a lot of foreign keys(customer_id) and I want to insert a comment row for each foreign key to comment table with same values.

```
insert into comment (customer_id, content, modified_date, modified_by, created_date, created_by, is_deleted, [application])
values(select id from customer 
       where id in(66417,65407,82589,71318,82915... many FKs), 'this is the new string value', NULL, 0, GETDATE(), 110, 0, 0);
```

It gives error like this:

```
Incorrect syntax near ','
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VALUES` is not needed just use `SELECT` statement with `INSERT INTO ..` :

```
insert into comment (customer_id, content, modified_date, modified_by, created_date, created_by, is_deleted, [application])
    select id, 'this is the new string value', NULL, 0, GETDATE(), 110, 0, 0
    from customer 
    where id in (66417,65407,82589,71318,82915... many FKs);
```

You can use constant expression with `SELECT` statement.